# How to avoid loading unnecessary desktop images while making mobile-friendly site(responsive)

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a web-site and I want to make it as easy(light-weight) for mobile as possible. I want to replace the heavy-weight images with the light ones, but not really sure what are the right way to do so.

I thought the "display: none" will solve the problem, but seems like it is not(please correct me if I'm wrong). Doesn't "display: none" should do the job here? If so, what should I do - I want a css solution as my site basically running with html'n'css code and a slider(using JQuery for it).

P.S. the "display: none" still load the heavy images

UPDATE:
Seems like no other solution than just use(if possible) images as a background ones(will need to adapt it, well). But this way I can actually make the "display:none" to work! WOOHOO!

Well, I guess we all learn from mistakes :)

If you have any other way, please... PLEASE, do share it!

Comment: Show us some code?

Comment: What for, man... no need for that

Comment: To be honest the W3C recommendations (Sorry, I can't find the specific link at present) was/are that for best results a mobile view should be using a different website than a desktop view. For instance wikipedia mobile is a different website to wikipedia standard. If you're this concerned about slack bandwidth I would suggest this approach.

Comment: I'm actually using different style for my site, but not a different site(wow, are they really think it's a better way?) - it's lot of more easy to change and adopt it for mobile with @media queries... at least in my case/for me

Comment: you can also optimize your images using http://tinypng.com/

Comment: Yes, I know about it, but thanks Yasir! :)

Answer (score 0):

The images that their display is set to none, will still load. so it makes no difference. you should try lazy loading images. for example setting a loading (or any default image) for them and some attribute like `data-src` with real src and set their src as they come into view.

there are also some plugins for lazy loading images if you search:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: First time hearing about the "lazy images". Thanks, pal. Gonna take a look at it.

Comment: Reading about it at the moment... but this is a JS/JQuery solution. I don't wanna use it if it's not a dead-necessary thing or something. Thanks for helping tho

Comment: sometimes ago, I was just failing at anything, no matter how easy they were and how much hard I tried. I had changed my avatar to this and my name to failure.

Comment: Well, that's not funny at all. But it's a kind of a philosophic way to look at, you know... It's reminding me my failures as well, but hell, now they all seems funny, he-he(remind me of how dumb I was and... well, am :) ). Hope for the best for you buddy!